# Linking against libuv

Tags: d, libuv

I wanted to try using libuv in dlang. I downloaded the dlang bindings like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:tamediadigital/libuv.git
```

Now what I do next to get my "hello world" running?

I tried this:

```
ldc2 hello.d -luv
```

But it said:

```
ldc2: Unknown command line argument '-luv'.  Try: 'ldc2 -help'
ldc2: Did you mean '-v'?
```

I think I need to tell the compiler where the library bindings are located.
And then import something in the source code, probably with `import libuv;`?

Here is the 'hello world' code I want to "port" to D:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uv.h>

int main() {
    uv_loop_t *loop = malloc(sizeof(uv_loop_t));
    uv_loop_init(loop);

    printf("Now quitting.\n");
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    uv_loop_close(loop);
    free(loop);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the bindings github page: https://github.com/tamediadigital/libuv

Library home page: http://www.libuv.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First that was a wrong bindings, here are the good ones: https://github.com/changloong/libuv

Assuming you did `git clonegit@github.com:changloong/libuv.git` in current dir.

Compile:

```
ldc2 hello.d -I=libuv/deimos/libuv/ -I=libuv/ -L=-luv
```

The source:

```cpp
import uv;
import core.memory;
import std.stdio;

int main(){
    uv_loop_t *loop = new uv_loop_t;
    uv_loop_init(loop);

    printf("Now quitting.\n");
    uv_run(loop, uv_run_mode.UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    uv_loop_close(loop);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps someone to get started with using C libs in D.